# How to make multiple save calls atomic in reactive spring data cassandra?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-cassandra

The scenario is that, I have a cassandra API which needs to save data in 3 tables/repositories. So, once the API is hit, either data should be persisted in all the tables or in none of them. How do I acheive this?

The microservice is based on spring boot and web flux and ofcourse reactive spring data cassandra.

I know that batching is still not available for reactive cassandra.

Can the zip operator be of any help here if I zip the 3 save calls using the operator? (I suspect, it won't be helpful)

Insights on this will be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right ..there was no support for BatchOperations in reactive cassandra but they have introduced it in version
2.1 RC2 check [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-574)

As an alternative you can club you individual statements in Batch and use.

Comment: Hey, can you comment on the use of zip operator used to combine the three save calls?